# How do I not echo WMIC in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, wmic

I am running the below command as part of a logon script, and would like to make sure the result isn't echoed:

`wmic qfe | find "3033929"`

I tried placing an `@` before the line but don't really know what else to try.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefixing with `@` tells `cmd` not to echo the command before executing it.

```
wmic qfe | find "3033929" >nul
```

sends the output of the `find` to *nowhere*. `errorlevel` will still be set (0=found, non-0=not found)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below option for `wmic` to suppress output from `wmic`

```
wmic /output:CLIPBOARD qfe
```

But then your `find` would not work since it won't get any input.

I think you need to re-direct the output of the whole command as shown below to a file so that nothing is echoed to the screen/console

```
wmic qfe | find "3033929" > wmic.out
```

You can then look at `wmic.out` for the results